# How to foreach array whitout get Catchable fatal error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hi i have a problem with looping array with foreach. I have this array:

```
        stdClass Object
    (
        [GetAllCitiesResult] => stdClass Object
            (
                [status] => Success
                [returnValue] => SoapVar Object
                    (
                        [enc_type] => 0
                        [enc_value] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [City] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => 7326
                                                [name] => Paris
                                                [postCode] => 7700
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [id] => 262
                                                [name] => Berlin
                                                [postCode] => 2932
                                            )
                                    )

                            )

                        [enc_stype] => ArrayOfCity
                        [enc_ns] => http://example.com/services/v1.1
                    )

            )

    )
```

And I try to loop with this PHP code:

```
    echo "<select>";
     foreach($result as $citys) {
    echo "<option>" . $citys . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

When I try this code it show me this error "Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line X"

I would like to check the object "status" every time run the code and I would like the object name from array "City" to get in dropdown list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your'e trying to print $cities, which isn't a string, it's a stdClass.

You need to navigate through the array until you have City as your initial array and then you can do

```
 foreach($city as $cityRecord){
    print '<option>' . $cityRecord['name'] . '</option'>
 }
```

Hopefully that'll help